# вывести на экран сумму всех чисел, расположенных в числовом промежутке от Х до У

Tags: javascript

У меня задание, вывести на экран сумму всех чисел, расположенных в числовом промежутке от Х до У.

```js
var x = prompt("Введите число","");
var y = prompt("Введите число","");
var sum = 0;

while (x<y)
{
  x++;
  
  if(x<y) 
    {
      sum+=x;
    }
}    
document.write(sum);
```

Код работает, но если первое число однозначное а второе двузначное то результат - 0. Если оба значение двузначные - код работает. Если вместо prompt использовать фиксированное значение, к примеру, 8 и 15 то код работает.

Comment: Наверно, всё-таки, найти надо сумму всех **целых** чисел, расположенных между данными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы складываете и сравниваете **СТРОКИ**, которые получили от пользователя, приведите их а [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Например вот так, за счет особенностей приведения типов в js:

```
var x = +prompt("Введите число","");
```

Или так, явно вызвывая функцию `Number`:

```
var x = Number(prompt("Введите число",""))
```

Целое можно попробовать получить вот так:

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Введите число",""));
```

```js
var x = +prompt("Введите число","");
        var y = Number(prompt("Введите число",""));
        var sum = 0;
    
        while (x<y)
        {
          x++;
          
          if(x<y) 
            {
              sum+=x;
            }
        }    
        document.write(sum);
```

Comment: Вот конструктор числа тут зря

Comment: @AlexeyTen why not? я еще мог BigInt написать =)

Comment: Потому что он возвращает объект, а не число. Можно вызвать просто Number как функцию. Практически не существует причин в реальном коде вызывать конструкторы примитивов

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes#primitivy "Конструкторы String/Number/Boolean – только для внутреннего использования". Там есть примеры, почему это плохо

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, да спасибо за правку

Comment: @AlexeyTen просто с Вашем первом сообщении не подчеркнуто слово конструктор и я не понял о чем вы =)

Answer (score 0):

Как написал Stranger in the Q:
Вы складываете и сравниваете строки, приведите их к Number, так:

```
var x = +prompt("Введите число","");
```

или так:

```
var x = new Number(prompt("Введите число",""));
```

Добавлю, что вместо цикла можно использовать формулу арифметической прогрессии
Что-то типа

```
sum=(x+y)*(x-y-1)/2;
```